# Google Script: Auto-trigger - if a new entry flags serious issue, spreadsheet emails admin for inspection

Tags: google-apps-script

I am pretty new to scripting. Please forgive, if I've missed an obvious step. I've searched through stack overflow, and my simple problem is not clearly mentioned.

We have a fleet of vans. The drivers enter issues through google forms, and it's added to a single google spreadsheet which has sheet/tabs for each vehicle. I want an email to be triggered once a new entry is made with the "serious issue found" and "Critical Immediate Action Requested" flag found in the drivers report.
(Spreadsheet is called "Fleet_Vehicles") (Each van is its own internal sheet: "Van_05-10" "Van_06-12" "Van_07-13") (The sheet meant for storing data (emails) for the script: Auto-Script-Logic)

This is google script I am attempting:
UPDATED: as per Coopers and Miturbe's input. Thank you gentlemen.

```
function CheckStatus() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("120u_KtdWValZXUyn8vaAlEqbNwmRROYMj-fFTx8bPOs");
  var FleetHealthRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Van_16-23"); 
  var row = ss.getLastRow();   var columns = ss.getLastColumn();   var range = ss.getRange(row, 1, 5, columns).getValues();
  var FleetHealth = FleetHealthRange.getValue();
  if ("How_serious?" == "Serious Symptom Discovered")
  if ("How_serious?" == "Critical Immediate Action Requested"){
      var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Auto-Script-Logic").getRange("A1");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
    var message = '(=sum(Van_16-23!A2:E20)'
    var subject = 'This Van 16-23 has serious symptom';
    MailApp.sendEmail('#####@gmail.com', subject, message);
    }
```

Am I missing an embarrassing and obvious symantec?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, with the code ".getRange (E2); " you are always reading the exact same cell every time. Is this desired? it is not reading the new line.

Comment: You are correct, that would be an issue. How do I have it read the latest line?

Comment: ".getLastRow" is the method. Just trying to figure out the semantic of adding that to the line.

Comment: this will read the last line of the sheet at store in an array "range"  `var row = ss.getLastRow();
  var columns = ss.getLastColumn();
  var range = ss.getRange(row, 1, 1, columns).getValues();`

Comment: Thank you miturbe, I've applied your entry, and trying to make it work. I've updated the original post. It gets an error "Exception: The parameters (String,number,number,number) don't match the method signature for" Not sure what that is referring too. I tryied to apend your suggestion, replacing the specific E2 mention. Perhaps, I should try adding the "GetSheetByName" command at the beginning of your suggested code? THANK YOU IN ADVANCE! :) I've learned a lot from these suggestions. Hope I never make the same mistakes twice.

Comment: I think it should be: "  var row = ss.getLastRow();   var range = ss.getRange(row, 1, 5, columns).getValues();"  The last Row and 5 columns.

Comment: Can you share a public copy of the sheet? Have you managed to make it work? If not, what is the issue right now?

Comment: Absolutely, thanks Kessy https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/120u_KtdWValZXUyn8vaAlEqbNwmRROYMj-fFTx8bPOs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you managed to solve it? If not, at what point are you right now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function CheckStatus() {
  var FleetHealthRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(Van_05-11).getRange("E2"); 
  var FleetHealth = FleetHealthRange.getValue();
   if (How serious? == "Serious Symptom Discovered"){
      var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Auto-Script-Logic").getRange("A1");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
    var message = 'This Van has serious symptom ' + FleetHealth; // Second column
    var subject = '(=sum(Van_05-11!D2)';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
}

How Serious is undefined and if it's a variable it needs to be one string without spaces.
```

[JavaScript Variable Naming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Guidelines/Code_guidelines/JavaScript#Variables)

Comment: That does look better! and thanks for the tip for "How_serious?". I'm trying to save and it says: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '==' (line 4, file "Code.gs")"  is that a noob mistake on my part? I'm probably forgetting something

Comment: You actually have a lot of problems in your coding when you supplying a string parameter you must put quote around it.  You might want to do some basic javascript tutorials online.

Comment: Thank you for your help Cooper! yes you are correct, I was missing quotes. I will square away sometime to go through some more beginners tutorials. Having said that, this looks like it should work now, but no idea why it does not?:  (I removed my email address in this example)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
function CheckStatus() {
  //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("120u_KtdWValZXUyn8vaAlEqbNwmRROYMj-fFTx8bPOs");
  
  var FleetHealthRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Van_16-23"); 
  
  var row = FleetHealthRange.getLastRow();   
  var columns = FleetHealthRange.getLastColumn();   
  var range = FleetHealthRange.getRange(row, 1, 1, columns).getValues();
  
  // By default, range is a 2D array so range[0][0] has the first column
  var lastrow = range[0];
  
  Logger.log("Reading row " + row + " columns " + columns)
  
  //var FleetHealth = FleetHealthRange.getValue();
  var column_serious = 5 //column number you want to compare, in this case 5 is column E
  
  if (lastrow[column_serious] == "Serious Symptom Discovered" || lastrow[column_serious] == "Critical Immediate Action Requested")
  {
      var emailAddress = lastrow[0];
      var message = '(=sum(Van_16-23!A2:E20)'
      var subject = 'This Van 16-23 has serious symptom';
      MailApp.sendEmail('#####@gmail.com', subject, message);
    
  }
  
}
```

I placed the code here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/197oWwBDmB0iI3Ry9Km6mfO73Jjx9RWjXHI-bAM28bZs/edit?usp=sharing